# How do I change a string value to a timestamp? Javascript React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, time

I have a start date job that I want to add an amount of days to, that the user enters. ( as a duration for the job)
I want to find out what the last date of the job will be by adding the duration to the starting date.

The starting date is being saved as a timestamp but the duration as a string.

Can I add the two together and get a final value as a timestamp?

Comment: What do you mean by "the starting date is ... a timestamp"? Do you mean a string like "23 Aug 2021" or as a number like 1629640800000? Both are [*timestamps*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp).

Comment: @RobG a number like 1629640800000.

Comment: The timestamp is already treated like a `Number`, you can even try to `console.log(typeof Date.now())` to verify it. Just change the String to Number as well (you can use `ParseInt`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the timestamp into date object then add the duration in the date  after that again convert it back to time stamp

**Example**

```
const timestamp = 1629640800000

const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
console.log(date) // Wed Apr 06 53611 13:00:00

const hours = date.getHours() 
console.log(hours) // 13

//suppose you want to add 4 hours in the existing date-time

date.setHours(hours + 4);
console.log(date) // Wed Apr 06 53611 17:00:00

// now converting back to timestamp

Date.parse(date)
console.log(date) // 1629640814400000
```

Comment: 6 Apr 53611 indicates that the time value probably shouldn't be multiplied by 1,000. `Date.parse(date)` is very inefficient, it should be `date.getTime()` or `date.valueOf()` or just `+date`.